# How to bootstrap .NET 3.5 SP1 with msbuild? following found instructions doesn't work

Tags: visual-studio-2010, .net-3.5, msbuild, bootstrapper

I'm trying to use msbuild GenerateBootstrapper task to distribute a .net application with the framework, without the need of internet connection to install it.

I've found many posts that all lead to the same instructions in here:

[Enable Samesite for the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 bootstrapper](http://download.microsoft.com/download/A/2/8/A2807F78-C861-4B66-9B31-9205C3F22252/VS2008SP1Readme.htm)

After following the instructions, I still cannot generate the bootstrapper. The more obvious issue I can see is that extracting the files from dotNetFx35.exe does not extract the same list of files and folders than shown on the readme file (for example TOOLS folders are not there).

What am I doing wrong? Am I following old instructions?

msbuild errors are as follows:

```
C:\svn\GII\5.1b\Installer\src\Installer\Installer.wixproj(103,5): error MSB3152: The install location for prerequisites has not been set to 'component vendor's web site' and the file 'DotNetFX35SP1\TOOLS\clwireg.exe' in item '.NET Framework 3.5 SP1' can not be located on disk. See Help for more information.
C:\svn\GII\5.1b\Installer\src\Installer\Installer.wixproj(103,5): error MSB3152: The install location for prerequisites has not been set to 'component vendor's web site' and the file 'DotNetFX35SP1\TOOLS\clwireg_x64.exe' in item '.NET Framework 3.5 SP1' can not be located on disk. See Help for more information.
C:\svn\GII\5.1b\Installer\src\Installer\Installer.wixproj(103,5): error MSB3152: The install location for prerequisites has not been set to 'component vendor's web site' and the file 'DotNetFX35SP1\TOOLS\clwireg_ia64.exe' in item '.NET Framework 3.5 SP1' can not be located on disk. See Help for more information.
C:\svn\GII\5.1b\Installer\src\Installer\Installer.wixproj(103,5): warning MSB3165: The value of the 'PublicKey' attribute in '.NET Framework 3.5 SP1' does not match that of file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX35SP1\dotNetFX30\XPSEPSC-x86-en-US.exe'.
C:\svn\GII\5.1b\Installer\src\Installer\Installer.wixproj(103,5): warning MSB3165: The value of the 'PublicKey' attribute in '.NET Framework 3.5 SP1' does not match that of file 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages\DotNetFX35SP1\dotNetFX30\XPSEPSC-amd64-en-US.exe'.
C:\svn\GII\5.1b\Installer\src\Installer\Installer.wixproj(103,5): error MSB3152: The install location for prerequisites has not been set to 'component vendor's web site' and the file 'DotNetFX35SP1\dotNetMSP\x86\NetFX2.0-KB948609-v6001-x86.msu' in item '.NET Framework 3.5 SP1' can not be located on disk. See Help for more information.
C:\svn\GII\5.1b\Installer\src\Installer\Installer.wixproj(103,5): error MSB3152: The install location for prerequisites has not been set to 'component vendor's web site' and the file 'DotNetFX35SP1\dotNetMSP\x86\NetFX3.0-KB948610-v6001-x86.msu' in item '.NET Framework 3.5 SP1' can not be located on disk. See Help for more information.
C:\svn\GII\5.1b\Installer\src\Installer\Installer.wixproj(103,5): error MSB3152: The install location for prerequisites has not been set to 'component vendor's web site' and the file 'DotNetFX35SP1\dotNetMSP\x64\NetFX2.0-KB948609-v6001-x64.msu' in item '.NET Framework 3.5 SP1' can not be located on disk. See Help for more information.
C:\svn\GII\5.1b\Installer\src\Installer\Installer.wixproj(103,5): error MSB3152: The install location for prerequisites has not been set to 'component vendor's web site' and the file 'DotNetFX35SP1\dotNetMSP\x64\NetFX3.0-KB948610-v6001-x64.msu' in item '.NET Framework 3.5 SP1' can not be located on disk. See Help for more information.
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've resolved the issue. The link provided by Microsoft's documentation to download the full .net framework 3.5 SP1 is not correct. The package from [.NET Framework 3.5 SP1 full install package](http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/0/e/20e90413-712f-438c-988e-fdaa79a8ac3d/dotnetfx35.exe) does have the expected files inside.

Comment: i have found that additionally to 3.5SP1 fix that has been mention in Mohsen answer is required to have both packages DotNetFX35 and DotNetFX35SP1 in Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages folder

Answer (score 3):

take a look at this

> Hello All,
>
> Let me shed some light on this issue.
>
> We are still investigating why the
>   Public Key Tokens of the actual files
>   are different than what we have in the
>   product.xml files.  Needless to say,
>   something slipped by despite our
>   testing.  You have my apologies for
>   that.
>
> The good news is that the bootstrapper
>   works quite well in this situation. 
>   When we build, we compare the digital
>   signature of the file on disk to the
>   PublicKeyToken listed in the
>   product.xml or package.xml.  If they
>   are different, then we use the value
>   of the actual file on disk, since this
>   is what will be copied and/or posted
>   in a "Same Location as my Application"
>   scenario.  This way, the bootstrapper
>   works correctly.
>
> We do show a build warning, to alert
>   the developer / builder that something
>   is different than was expected.  This
>   has value in the "Download from the
>   Component Vendor's Web Site" scenario
>   because if the file being downloaded
>   from the Component vendor is the same
>   as is on disk, then the download will
>   fail the certificate test and won't
>   install.  Fortunately, in this case,
>   in that scenario only the
>   dotnetfx35setup.exe file is actually
>   downloaded from Microsoft, and that
>   key is correct.
>
> If you wish to get rid of the build
>   warnings, you can update your
>   PublicKey in the Product.XML with the
>   following value:
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
>
> Use this for both of the XPSEPSC*
>   files.
>
> I hope this helps to clarify things,
>   and we are going to continue to
>   follow-up. Thank you for reporting
>   this, it will help us keep more people
>   from running into this.
>
> Sincerely,
>
> David Guyer Program Manager - Setup
>   Projects Visual Studio