# Using a bootstrapper for .net 3.5 with WiX and Visual Studio 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010, wix

I am using Visual Studio 2010 to create a WiX project. I want to install .net 3.5 for my software and .net 4.0 for WiX. I used the bootstrappers available with VS2010. It worked for the 4.0 version, but I have problems with the 3.5 version. Here are some lines from my code :

```
<BootstrapperFile Include=".NETFramework,Version=v4.0" >
  <ProductName>.NET Framework 4.0</ProductName>
</BootstrapperFile>
<BootstrapperFile Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1" >
  <ProductName>.NET Framework 3.5 SP1</ProductName>
</BootstrapperFile>

<GenerateBootstrapper ApplicationFile="$(TargetFileName)"
                  ApplicationName="My Application Name"
                  BootstrapperItems="@(BootstrapperFile)"
                  ComponentsLocation="Relative"
                  CopyComponents="True"
                  OutputPath="$(OutputPath)"
                  Path="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\"/>
```

First I had the error :

The install location for prerequisites has not been set to ‘component vendor’s web site’ and the file ‘dotNetFx35setup.exe’ in item ‘Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1’ cannot be located on disk.

I followed the instructions found here :

http://sebastienlachance.com/blog/the-install-location-for-prerequisites-has-not-been-set-to-component-vendors-web-site-and-the-file-dotnetfx35setupexe-in-item-microsoftnetframework35sp1-cannot-be-located-on-disk

But now I have a new warning :

Item 'Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1' could not be located in 'C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\'.

I don’t understand what happens. I googled a lot and looked at similar questions, but didn’t find any precise answer… Does anybody have a solution, or is there another way to install prerequisites with WiX on VS2010 ?

Thanks !

Comment: I would reccomend targeting a single version of the .NET framework for your app and Wix custom actions so you only have to install a single framework package.  Did you adjust the instructions for the SDK version 7.0A (replace any 6.0As from the instructions with 7.0A)?

Comment: Yes I adjusted the instructions. Concerning the single version of .NET : I really need to install both since WiX and my app don't need the same version... If I only install the 4.0 version, my app, which needs 3.5, won't run, right ?

Comment: That is correct, if your app targets 3.5, you need 3.5.  Can you target your app to 4.0?

Comment: No, I can't target the app to 4.0. In fact, I can't do anything on the app, I have to adapt the installer...

Comment: Why do you need .NET 4.0 for Wix?  Wix 3.5 does not require the .NET framework unless you have custom actions written in a .NET language.  Also, can you include the `<Product` tag from `C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\DotNETFX35SP1\product.xml`?

Comment: Maybe this SO post will help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3626672/how-to-bootstrap-net-3-5-sp1-with-msbuild-following-found-instructions-doesnt

Comment: @heavyd I don't understand your last question : in the product.xml, there was : <Product xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper" ProductCode="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1">. I included the ProductCode in my code.

Comment: @BryanJ I had already seen this post. I had followed the instructions they are talking about, but my problem was after doing all this.

Answer (score 0):

On a 64-bit system, the value of the `Path` attribute of the `GenerateBootstrapper` XML element should start with `C:\Program Files (x86)\`. You are missing the `(x86)` part.

You can check the bitness of your OS by hitting <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>pause</kbd> and examining the "System type".

Comment: On my system, the path is C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\, I have checked it.

Answer (score 0):

You have set the path as

```
Path="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\"
```

it may need to be

```
Path="C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bootstrapper\Packages"
```

Navigate to that path and make sure the bootstrapper packages are in fact there. Specifically, you should have a folder named something like *DotNetFX35SP1* and inside it should be a *Product.xml* file that has the same product code element that matches your Bootstrapper include item. So...

```
<BootstrapperFile Include="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1" >
```

should match

```
ProductCode="Microsoft.Net.Framework.3.5.SP1"
```

Comment: The `Path` is set correctly.  The `GenerateBootstrapper` task looks for the bootstrapper engine under `{PATH}\Engine` and packages under `{PATH}\Packages`.

Comment: @heavyd thanks for pointing that out. I wrongly assumed the issue was just pointing to the correct location of the bootstrapper packages. Should have tried it myself first.